# Transfer/Access table values from one database server to another

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using SQL SERVER 2012.

I have a stored procedure where i create a temporary table called RESULT which carries result-set of an inner-join.

```
     SELECT column(s)
     FROM [database1].[table1]
     INNERJOIN
     [database2].[table2]
```

The result-set is processed from tables in DB SERVER 1.

Now,I have to insert the result set inside another table present in DB SERVER 2.

```
Select * from [server2].[Table1].dbo.User WHERE UserID = Result.UserID
```

How to access the database of Server2 table from Server1 table?

Answer (score 1):

I would say the easiest option would be to use a linked server (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ff772782.aspx)

Then you can query the server using

```
SELECT * 
FROM [SERVER].[DATABASE].[SCHEMA].[TABLE] t1
INNER JOIN [DATABASE2].[TABLE2] t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: thanks for responding ,I followed msdn post you shared. but still facing issue.Unable to connect to server.

Comment: It's not a simple thing to setup some of the time. If you'd like me to help troubleshoot, I'd need more information as to how your environment is configured and how you created the linked server.